# Regular Expression to match strings

Tags: regex

I want to match all the strings satifying following rules-

- should consist of *lower-case* letters and digits and dashes
- should start with a letter or a number
- should end with a letter or number
- total string length should be atleast 3 and atmost 20 characters
- dot `.` is optional, there shouldn't be two or more consecutive dots `.`
- dash `-` is optional, there shouldn't be two or more consecutive dashes `-`
- dot `.` and dash `-` shouldn't be consecutive // the string `aaa.-aaabbb` is invalid
- underscore not allowed

I have come up with this regex:

```
^[a-z0-9]([a-z0-9]+\.?\-?[a-z0-9]+){1,18}[a-z0-9]$

[a-z0-9] //should start/end with a letter or a number
([a-z0-9]+\.?\-?[a-z0-9]+){1,18}  //other rules
```

However it is failing in some scenarios like -

```
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz //should fail total number of chars greater than 20  
aaa.-aaabbb //should fail as dot '.' and dash '-' are consecutive
```

Can anyone please help me in correcting this regex?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this with a [lookahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
^(?!.*[.-]{2})[a-z0-9][a-z0-9.-]{1,18}[a-z0-9]$
```

**Explanation:**

```
^                # Start of string
(?!              # Assert that the following can't be matched:
 .*              #  Any number of characters
 [.-]{2}         #  followed by .. or -- or .- or -.
)                # End of lookahead
[a-z0-9]         # Match lowercase letter/digit
[a-z0-9.-]{1,18} # Match 1-18 of the allowed characters
[a-z0-9]         # Match lowercase letter/digit
$                # End of string
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Tim for your quick reply and pointer to the Lookahead link :-)

Answer (score 1):

I came up with this which uses a [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) similar to Tim's solution but a different way of appying it. Because it only does the look ahead when it sees a dot or a dash it may not need to do quite so much [back tracking](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html) which may make it perform very slightly faster.

```
^[a-z0-9]([a-z0-9]|([-.](?![.-]))){1,18}[a-z0-9]$
```

Explanation:

```
^                  # Start of string
[a-z0-9]           # Must start with a letter or number
(                  # Begin Group
   [a-z0-9]        # Match a letter or number
   |               # OR
   ([-.](?![.-]))  # Match a dot or dash that is not followed by a dot or dash
){1,18}            # Match group 1 to 18 times
[a-z0-9]           # Must end with a letter or number
$                  # End of string
```